# Django TypeError: url() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 16 were given

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am very new to Django and have hit another stumbling block. I am integrating a separate third party auction app into my own project and before integrating into my own I get errors in the app. I seem to be getting url errors for each of the urls.

```
   Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0340E810>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\auction_site\YAAS\urls.py", line 31, in <module>
    (r'^bidauction/(?P<id>\w+)/$', bid_auction),
TypeError: url() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 16 were given
```

Below is my url file

```
# from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url from django.conf.urls import include, url from django.urls import path from YAASApp.views import * from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = url('',
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'^', include('YAASApp.urls')),
    (r'^home/$', home),
    (r'^createuser/$', register),
    (r'^login/$', login),
    (r'^logout/$', logout),
    (r'^edituser/$',edit_user_info),
    (r'^addauction/$',add_auction),
    (r'^saveauction/$',save_auction),
    (r'^editauction/(?P<id>\w+)/$', edit_auction),
    (r'^saveeditedauction/(?P<id>\w+)/$',save_edited_auction),
    (r'^canceledit/(?P<id>\w+)/$',canceledit),
    (r'^auction/(?P<id>\w+)/$', view_auction),
    (r'^banauction/(?P<id>\w+)/$', ban_auction),
    (r'^changelang/$', changelang),
    # (ur'^search/(\w+)/$', search),
    # (ur'^search/$', search),
    (r'^bidauction/(?P<id>\w+)/$', bid_auction),

    #url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

    # (ur'^api/v1/search/$', apisearch),
    # (ur'^api/v1/search/(\w+)/$', apisearch),

    # (ur'^api/v2/bid/(?P<id>\w+)/$', apibid),

    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls), )
```

Comment: I don't see an url file?

Comment: you need to uncomment the last bracket

Comment: It looks like the auction app was written for a very old version of Django, because it's using code written for Django 1.7 or older. I'd think carefully about whether it's a good idea to use this app. You might need to make lots of changes to make it work with a current Django release, which you might find difficult if you are new to Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlpatterns` should be a *list* of patterns. You have,

```
urlpatterns = url('',
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
)
```

which is causing the error. It looks similar to the syntax `urlpatterns = patterns('',` which was deprecated in Django 1.8.

It should be something like:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/$', home), 
    url(r'^createuser/$', register),
    ...
]
```

Note you can't use tuples like `(r'^home/$', home),`. You must either use `url()` or `re_path` with regexes, e.g. `url(r'^home/$', home),`, or use the new `path()` syntax.

Comment: AS ALWAYS Alasdair. Top Coder